# character array in c to c#

Tags: c#, c, arrays, char

I have the following code in C, 
Its basically a maze where

S=starting point G=Goal .=open path and #=dead end

```
char maze[6][6] = {
    "S...##",
    "#.#...",
    "#.##.#",
    "..#.##",
    "#...#G",
    "#.#..."
};
```

I am trying to convert into c#, here is my attempt

```
char[,] maze = new char[6,6];
```

I don't know how to add the 2dimensional array into this object. basically I want the maze layout in C#.

I also want to be ably to access a point in my maze, for example maze[x][y]=="S" for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char[,]` solution is probably the one you want to use but just for kicks if you just need to access elements as `maze[y][x]' you can use your old code with a slight twist:

```
string[] maze = new []{
    "S...##",
    "#.#...",
    "#.##.#",
    "..#.##",
    "#...#G",
    "#.#..."
};
```

You'll have to remember that this is an array of `string` not `char` but strings model a sequence of chars.  This won't work if you intend on modifying individual elements (like say `maze[3][2] = '.'` as strings are immutable.

Answer (score 3):

```
char[,] maze = new char[6,6]
{
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f'},
    {'g','h','i','j','k','l'},
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f'},
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f'},
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f'},
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f'}
};
```

**Edit:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
char[,] myArray = new char[6, 6] 
{
    { 'S','.','.','.','#','#' }, 
    { '#','.','#','.','.','.' }, 
    { '#','.','#','#','.','#' }, 
    { '.','.','#','.','#','#' }, 
    { '#','.','.','.','#','G' }, 
    { '#','.','#','.','.','.' }, 
};
```